ROC curve *without* a model estimator?
I have created an AI Tool which extracts content from an image and then reviews that content for completeness and accuracy. I am trying to evaluate the performance of this tool and am gathering metrics to do so.
I have a resulting table that looks similar to the below; the true values come from manual ground truth reviews of documents and the predicted values are the actual output of the tool.
ID | true | predicted |
-----------------------
1  |  0   |      1    |
2  |  0   |      0    |
3  |  1   |      1    |
4  |  1   |      0    |

I have been able to use the true and predicted columns to obtain various metrics using the code below:
def calculate_metrics(df, true, predicted):
    accuracy = accuracy_score(df[true], df[predicted])
    precision = precision_score(df[true], df[predicted])
    recall = recall_score(df[true], df[predicted])
    f1 = f1_score(df[true], df[predicted])
    roc_auc = roc_auc_score(df[true], df[predicted])
    return print(f"accuracy: {accuracy}\nprecision: {precision}\nrecall: {recall}\nf1: {f1}\nroc_auc: {roc_auc}")

Additionally, I would like to plot a ROC curve. I am able to obtain the roc_auc score and assumed I could plot from there, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how exactly to do so. It looks like I need a model estimator to determine probabilities and then from there I can create the plot but I'm unclear how to do so with the data I've obtained.
Is it even possible to create a ROC curve using the results I have and, if so, how do I do so?


Is it even possible to create a ROC curve using the results I have and, if so, how do I do so?

No. You need to have the model produce the probability that an observation falls into a class, rather than the predicted class. The point of an ROC curve is that it allows you to visualize how different thresholds for probability of determining that the data falls into either class affects the true positive rate and false positive rate.
However, this data is after thresholding, which means that you can't visualize the effect of different thresholds. You need your model to output a probability rather than the predicted class in order to perform this visualization.

That makes complete sense, thank you for the clear and thorough explanation.

The answer holds in most circumstances, but I would add a nuance that it depends on what the predicted field really represents. Some models (like decision tree) can produce outputs as discrete probabilities (aka 0 or 1). So we could very well draw an Roc curve. It might just not be as helpful because there is no threshold to select.

@SachinHosmani That's a valid point. On the other hand, although technically one can draw this curve, but I don't think its a particularly helpful visualization. It has three points, and two of them are fixed by the definition of the ROC curve, so you have only one point which varies based on the accuracy of your classifier. You could get the same information by printing out the false positive rate and true positive rate of the single non-fixed point.

It depends on whether your predicted is the actual probability or a thresholded probability. I see 0s and 1s for predicted so it's quite possible that they are thresholded already so you've lost the original probabilities, so it wouldn't be possible to accurately plot the ROC curve.
But if whatever model produced this actually produced only 0s or 1s as the probabilities (for example, a decision tree model could learn to predict discrete outputs like that), then you can very well produce an ROC curve with that. It might not be useful (since there is no need to select a threshold), and it might just not look smooth and might look something like this:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

data = [
    {'ID': 1, 'true': 0, 'predicted': 1},
    {'ID': 2, 'true': 0, 'predicted': 0},
    {'ID': 3, 'true': 1, 'predicted': 1},
    {'ID': 4, 'true': 1, 'predicted': 0},
    {'ID': 5, 'true': 0, 'predicted': 0},
    {'ID': 6, 'true': 1, 'predicted': 1},
    {'ID': 7, 'true': 1, 'predicted': 1},
    {'ID': 8, 'true': 0, 'predicted': 1},
    {'ID': 9, 'true': 1, 'predicted': 0},
    {'ID': 10, 'true': 0, 'predicted': 0}
]

true_labels = np.array([item['true'] for item in data])
predicted_probs = np.array([item['predicted'] for item in data])

fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(true_labels, predicted_probs)
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='darkorange', lw=2, label=f'ROC curve (area = {roc_auc:.2f})')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=2, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()


